# Download an image generated dynamically rather than display in browser

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, fileresult

I created a Action that convert the content of an URL(HTML) into an Image (JPG), and than, return it to me, however, the browser is downloading it instead showing.

The Image is generated dynamically, I don't have it in hard disk.

My code is the following:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public FileResult URLToImage(string url)
{
    // In some cases you might want to pull completely different URL that is not related to your application.
    // You can do that by specifying full URL.
    UrlAsImage urlImg = new UrlAsImage(url)
    {
        FileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".jpg",
        PageHeight = 630,
        PageWidth = 1200
    };
    return File(urlImg.BuildFile(this.ControllerContext), "image/jpg", urlImg.FileName);
}
```

What do I need to do to show it in the browser instead downloading it?

Comment: Does using `image/jpeg` change anything?

Comment: whats your client side code, how are you trying to display the image.

Comment: @jero when I enter with the URL, the browser have to show me the image and not to download

Comment: @PaulAbbott I don't know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Return a FileResult and set the [Content-Disposition](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1806.txt) in the header to **Inline**

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public FileResult URLToImage(string url)
{
    // In some cases you might want to pull completely different URL that is not related to your application.
    // You can do that by specifying full URL.
    UrlAsImage urlImg = new UrlAsImage(url)
    {
        FileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".jpg",
        PageHeight = 630,
        PageWidth = 1200
    };
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename="+urlImg.FileName);
    return File(urlImg.BuildFile(this.ControllerContext), "image/jpg");
}
```